# Not able to Initialise smartmeter as ite generate an error?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, smartmeter

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozi6o.jpg) I have recorded test scrip using smart meter.
But I when I tries to load the script "Rum smartmeter Test"
It gives following.  I have no requirement of remote server as i wanted to run basic Testscript from local machine

*> Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused connect*

Just for the background please note that SmartMeter.io is based on Apache JMeter but adds new features such as one-click test reports, advanced scenario recorder, user friendly distributed mode, acceptance criteria and many others.

Looking forward for your suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you try to "Remote Start" instead of "Start"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SmartMeter is unable to start a load generator. The most common reason is that the required port `1099` is already occupied by some other program or the load generator can sometimes be blocked by your firewall. I suggest you restart your computer and try again. If it doesn't help, then you need to find out what is occupying that port. See for example [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

You should be able to get some information from `logs/generator.log`.

You can also run tests from SmartMeter Editor, the same way you would do in JMeter.